# What adds the string ".json" to a url?

Tags: json, url, parameters

It's a silly question, but we have noticed one user pretty constantly appends ".json" to the URL when navigating our website. This appended string breaks our url signature validation, so this user is being rejected quite a lot (and it's showing up in my error log daily, you decide which is worse).

I'm sure there's a browser plugin or something doing it, but I just can't figure out what would cause it.

We have a ColdFusion website that passes a few url params between pages, and often makes ajax get requests for JSON, but we don't ever append .json to the url.

Can you think of what might be causing this, or where I can look for an answer? If/when I know what might be doing this then I might ask another question about appropriate ways to handle it.

Thanks all!

Comment: Possibly a vulnerability scanner?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out a bit more about your user to understand the motivations. Look out for browser, OS, origin IP for example. If it's all within your normal user behaviour then potentially can be something on your customer device. If it is completely outside your user's normal behaviour might be that you are "under attack" and somebody or something is trying to find vulnerabilities in your website.

Cheers